# I'm trying to pack several files into an array, but only one is shown at a time

Tags: reactjs

I want to put multiple files into an array and then iterate over that.
At the moment I only get to the point where, for example, I select two files, only one is displayed.
And if I do a console output after the loop in the UploadFile function, then I always get an empty array displayed. Below, in the return block, however, I only ever get one element back from the Map method. No matter how many files I choose.

```
const [datei, setDatei] = React.useState([]);

const uploadFile = (e) => {

   let dateiNeu = e.target.files;

     for (var i = 0; i < dateiNeu.length; i++) {

      const newFile = dateiNeu[i];
      setDatei([...datei, newFile]);

     }

   // Length = 0  - WHY ?
      console.log(datei);

};
  
[...]
  

<Col md={12}>

        <input

        className={classes.input}

        id="contained-button-file"

        type="file"

        multiple

        onChange={(e) => uploadFile(e)}

      /> 

      <div className={classes.anhaenge}>
       //Only one element in the array is displayed
        {datei.map((d, index) => {

          return (


            <IconContext.Provider value={{ size: "50px" }}>

              <div>

                <FcFile></FcFile>

                {d.name}

              </div>

            </IconContext.Provider>

          );

        })}

      </div>

    </Col>
```

Comment: `setDatei([...datei, ...dateiNeu]);` - this is enough. No need of forloop

Comment: @ Sarun UK Why cumbersome when it works like this: D Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the state like below (no need to use `forloop`)

```
const uploadFile = (e) => {
   let dateiNeu = e.target.files;
   setDatei([...datei, ...dateiNeu]);
};
```